# Никак не могу понять ошибку привязки в MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Доброго времени суток, никак не могу понять почему нет привязки, буду благодарен за любую критику и наставления, спасибо.

Model:

```
public class Data : ViewModelBase

public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
public bool ServerState { get; set; }
public TimeSpan ServerTimeSpan { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Terminal> Terminals { get; set; }


public class Terminal : ViewModelBase

public string Protocol { get; set; }
public string SerialId { get; set; }
public string SimNumber { get; set; }
public string ConnectionTime { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<Sensor> Sensors;


public class Sensor : ViewModelBase

public string Type { get; set; }
public dynamic Value { get; set; }
```

ViewModel:

```
    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    private Data Data;

    public Data _data
    {
        get { return Data; }

        set
        {
            if (Data != value)
            {
                Data = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Data");
            }
        }
    }


    public DelegateCommand OpenFileCommand { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        OpenFileCommand = new DelegateCommand(obj => OpenFileExecute(), obj => true);
    }




    private async void OpenFileExecute()
    {
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        var dialogResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (!dialogResult.HasValue || !dialogResult.Value)
            return;
        var path = openFileDialog.FileName;

        var xmlParser = new XmlParser();
        var data = await xmlParser.ParseFile(path);

        _data = data;
    }
```

View:

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="269,347,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding OpenFileCommand}"/>
    <DataGrid Name="Terminals" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,158,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="243" Width="254" SelectedItem="{Binding _data.SelectedTerminal}" ItemsSource="{Binding _data.Terminals}"/>
    <DataGrid Name="Sensors" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="349,222,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="158" Width="169" RenderTransformOrigin="0.311,0.278" ItemsSource="{Binding _data.SelectedTerminal.Sensors}"/>
```

Тут привязываю контекст:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new ViewModel.ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Кстати, Output не ругается ни на что.

Comment: Так, а как проявляется ошибка?

Comment: Кстати, а где у вас в `Data` `SelectedTerminal`?

Comment: ошибка проявляется в том что GridView не выводит Terminals.

Comment: @VladD Оп, нашёл ошибку, **NotifyPropertyChanged("_data")** нужно было поставить, извините за невнимательность. Но задам наверное последений вопрос - каким образом можно получить доступ к полям объекта Data? Пример: 'public string ServerState = _data.ServerState.ToString()' ?

Comment: К _полям_ — никак, только к свойствам. Если класс реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`, то изменения свойства будут подхватываться, иначе — нет.

Answer (score 3):

Кажется, тут целая череда ошибок.

1. Мне кажется, что у вас ошибка ещё в XAML-коде. Вы биндитесь к
   приватному полю, когда надо к публичному свойству. Вместо 
   `ItemsSource="{Binding _data.Terminals}"` попробуйте
   `ItemsSource="{Binding Data.Terminals}"`.
2. Ваш класс Data даже фигурных скобок не содержит, поэтому, если весь первый фрагмент кода объявлен внутри класса Model, то все ваши свойства относятся к нему, а класс Data вообще пустой. Возможно это просто вы так сюда запостили, но впредь постите лучше код целиком из файла, от "юзингов" и до последней закрывающей скобки.
3. Ваш DataGrid ничего не отобразит даже если вы ручками вобьёте какие-нибудь значения, потому что вы выставили `AutoGenerateColums = false`, что означает, что вы должны сами написать XAML-код, для разметки колонок. Опять таки - не видно, что-бы он был. Вообще, очень неполные данные, что-бы ответить на вопрос наверняка.